# getting a response data in ajax using codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Hi i have this data which i want that only a certain div will refresh using ajax. How will i able to pass the json_encode to the ajax what will load the data on a certain div using codeigniter.
Heres my controller below

```
$this->data['getNumberOfMessages'] = $this->mm->getNumberOfMessages($this->data['id']);
$this->data['countNumber'] = $this->data['getNumberOfMessages'];

$responseOnject = new stdClass();
$responseOnject->status = 'ok';
$responseOnject->StatusMessages=$this->data['countNumber'];

$this->output->set_output(json_encode($responseOnject));
```

this line of code here

```
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($response));
```

outputs this one

```
{"status":"ok","StatusMessages":20}
```

and i want that to pass through my ajax in my code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var id =$(this).data("messageid");
     $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: $(this).data("href"),

        success: function(data){
            alert(data.StatusMessages);
            console.log(data.StatusMessages);

            $("#" + id + ' span.badge').html(data.StatusMessages);
        }
    });
});
```

and target on my certain div so that it will automatically refresh 
 below is my code

```
<tr>
    <th>
        <a href="#" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-messageid="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-href="<?php echo base_url().'profile'?>" title="messages">
        <span class="badge"><?php echo $countNumber; ?></span>
                    message(s)</a>
    </th>
</tr>
```

when i tried to `alert(data.StatusMessages);`it return undefined.
can someone pls help me figured this thing out? ive been stuck in this.. my code really works but i want to be ajax, only certain div refresh without refershing my entire page.
Any help is muchly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the right url? See what happens in the network tab.

Comment: how to see if my url is wrong?

Comment: Your browser's dev tools -> network tab. See what url is called. Or simply output the url somewhere. `$(this).data("href")` in the document context just doesn't seem right.

Comment: but it will display to this output
{"status":"ok","StatusMessages":20}

when i test it. so i think my url is correct

Comment: Ah, I see now, I'll write you an answer.

Comment: ok thanks pls post your answer here..

Comment: Hi, first you tell me you return the data or echo the data

Comment: @MukulBhardwaj its all in my code above the output data

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the response JSON first in order to be able to access it as a JS object. This is how it's done in JS:

```
JSON.parse(JSONStringHere);
```

So, your success callback should be:

```
success: function(data){
      data = JSON.parse(data); // this is what decodes JSON
      alert(data.StatusMessages);
      console.log(data.StatusMessages);

      $("#" + id + ' span.badge').html(data.StatusMessages);
    }
```

---

As I said in the comments, **you're not calling the right URL with AJAX** (although you said you do and that it returns that JSON string; if so, the code above **would work**). This doesn't look like it would give you a URL:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var id =$(this).data("messageid");
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: $(this).data("href"), // <---- what is the value of this?
```

Once you fix that, your code will work.

Comment: this code
JSON.parse(JSONStringHere);
should i put this on my controller?

Comment: No, just that one line `data = JSON.parse(data);`. You are already encoding the JSON in your controller, this is used to decode it on the client.

Comment: ive got this line error
0

ReferenceError: data is not defined
 

dataType: JSON.parse(data),

Comment: i think this line of code
 data = JSON.parse(data);
is wrong

Comment: I understood in your comment that your AJAX returns `{"status":"ok","StatusMessages":20}`, but it seems to return undefined (nothing). This means your code is **not** working, and you're probably calling a wrong URL from ajax.

Comment: but when im about to alert(data) without data.StatusMessages it will alert all the datas with the {"status":"ok","StatusMessages":20} and the html code so i think the data are returning when im about to alert data only

Comment: but when i add this line of code in my ajax
dataType: 'JSON',
it cannot alert

Comment: If `alert(data)` is working and showing the code, then my example above has to work. For a quick check try another alert: `alert(JSON.parse(data));`

Comment: error
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 36 of the JSON data
 

alert(JSON.parse(data));

Comment: Can you paste here exactly what `data` contains? Seems like you're echoing something more.

Comment: when i alert(data) this is the result
{"status":"ok","StatusMessages":21}<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- saved from url=(0074)header-light-dark/index.html -->

<html lang="en" class="sb-init"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initi

Comment: but when i alert(data.StatusMessages) undefined

Comment: No, your response just appends the JSON in front of what seems to be a full HTML page... You only need that JSON part, that's why it's breaking.

Comment: ahh i see but how to only outputs my json only this line only
{"status":"ok","StatusMessages":20}?

Comment: i think this line of code in codeigniter is wrong
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($responseOnject));

Comment: Ideally, you would have a separate controller or just a separate controller method just for that ajax call. The first output you do is fine, but, you seem to be outputting the whole page after, so I suspect that you're using the same method to render the page along, and to handle the ajax. If this is the case and you don't want a separate controller, or method, you should just prevent the output of the whole page if it was the ajax call. That way, your controller will **either** output the full page, **or** just the JSON part for that ajax call. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: but in my case is that ok??

Comment: Well, if you separate it so you can output either the JSON for AJAX or the full page, then you're good.

Answer (score 0):

For JSON data your controller should have the following line to output

**UPDATE**

Just noticed your problem is that codeigniter is outputting html along side your ajax response.

To Make this go away, Your code in the controller should be like this:

```
$this->output
     ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
     ->set_output(json_encode($responseOnject))
     ->_display();
exit;
```

This would force the output library to display & the exit to stop displaying anything else.

If you do not set the application/json content type, your response won't be treated as JSON And you'd have to use JSON.parse in your javascript code to convert it to json which is a bad practice.

Comment: hi when i tried your code then refrehes my entire page it will load an html code on it

Comment: I don't follow, what's your problem exactly? If you want the output to be within the badge, then you'll have to move the id="<?php echo $id; ?>" up to the <th> tag, as your targeting it wrong.

Comment: just trace my code on it. it is very understandable in my code

Comment: No your making it wrong.. i know what that mean that will display this output 
{"status":"ok","StatusMessages":21}

Comment: That's exactly how JSON output looks like, Clearly you have no idea what you're doing I have fixed the PHP part for you, You'll have to fix the javascript code which is also wrong. I am just setting you on the right track, And I have no obligation whatsoever to fix your entire code.

Comment: yes i know that is how JSON output looks like.. and it seems you are not able to get what im looking for